# Text into shapes with shape-inside or SVGs

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I'm looking for a **real solution** to the problem of making a **text flow** inside a **CSS-shape** or inside an **SVG-shape**.

[image]

On the internet, you can find many **partial solutions** like:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/
https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/index.html

All of them use "**shape-outside**" which is amazing for many purposes but in some cases it doesn't work well. That because these ways use two shapes with "shape-outside" and not **a single CSS-shape with "shape-inside"**.

So I'm asking my self:

1. **Does really exists "shape-inside"**?
2. If not, **is it going to be available** soon?
3. Does **something similar exist with SVGs**?

Comment: 1. [yes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextShapeInside) 2. no it won't be available soon, maybe not ever for SVG.

Comment: Thank you. If it exists can I use it? How? I saw some examples online but not working. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html. go to 11.4.2

Comment: It exists on a piece of paper, as I said already there are no implementations as far as I know, nor are there any plans to create implementations.